# Design a data structure to retrieve top trending keywords

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, twitter, heap

This question was posted on Leetcode [here](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/182303/Design-a-data-structure-to-retrieve-top-trending-keywords./).

**Design a data structure, that can return a top trending keyword. The time complexity should be as minimal as possible. TBH I don't know how yet, optimal the solution can be.**

Given 2 parameters as input:
Parameter 1: String Username
Parameter 2: Array of String containing the keywords tweeted by the user.

Function declaration: function tweet(username, keywords[]){};

Example 1:

```
tweet("User1",["love","dog"])
tweet("User2",["cat"])
tweet("User3",["walk","cat"])
tweet("User2",["dog"])
tweet("User3",["like","dog"])
```

top trending keyword : Dog

Example 2:

```
a. tweet("User1",["Dog"])
b. tweet("User1",["like","Dog"])
c. tweet("User1",["love","Dog"])
d. tweet("User1",["walk","Dog"])
e. tweet("User1",["hate","Dog"])
f. tweet("User2",["like","cat"])
g. tweet("User3",["cat"])
```

top trending keyword: cat
explanation: Only consider the number of unique users who tweeted a particular keyword while calculating the top trending keyword.

---

For this question, I was able to come up with a solution using (similar to one posted on Leetcode [here](http://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/182303/Design-a-data-structure-to-retrieve-top-trending-keywords./190697))
1. Map, which holds the set of words for a given user, 
2. Map which holds the word and it's unique user count.
3. Max Heap -> used to retrieve the top word based on the frequency.

However, for all the words that's already in Map 2, if I add it to the PQ, I need to do a remove operation which is O(n), and then add it again with increased frequency in the PQ.

E.g. in example 2 above, up to operation e

```
After a, Map1-[<User1,[Dog]>], Map2- [[<Dog,1>], PQ-[1-Dog]
After b, Map1-[[<User1,[Dog,like]>]], Map2- [<Dog,1>,<like,1>], PQ-[1-Dog,1-like]
```

...
After e,

```
Map1- [[<User1,[Dog,like,love,walk,hate]>]],
Map2- [<Dog,1>,<like,1>,<love,1>,<walk,1>,<hate,1>],
**PQ-[1-Dog,1-like,1-love,1-walk,1-hate]**
```

After f,

```
Map1- [<User1,[Dog,like,love,walk,hate]>,<User2,[like,cat]>],
Map2- [<Dog,1>,<like,2>,<love,1>,<walk,1>,<hate,1>,<cat,1>],
**PQ- [2-like,1-Dog,1-love,1-walk,1-hate]**
```

My question is: After adding entry "User2 - like,cat" in step f above, I need to re-balance the max heap, i.e. remove "like" and add it back. So that now it's at the top of the heap.

Is this the optimal way? Or I can optimize it further. So that I don't incur the cost of remove() or re-balancing.

I tried with a TreeMap too, but cannot figure out the data structures.

Comment: Whats the question again?

Comment: As the title says, we've to design an optimal data structure that returns the top trending keyword.

Comment: Plz explain the para "However, i feel....", is PQ = priority Queue? Is problem1 solved for you and You are struggling with just the followup?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example. Basically, I am concerned about the removal (or re-balancing) of heap cost. i.e. I'll have to remove the entry for word "like" and add it back.